# How do I dismiss the input number?

Tags: python, loops

I have written a code with the instructions "Write a while loop that prints user_num divided by 2 until user_num is less than 1. The value of user_num changes inside of the loop." My code is producing most of the correct output, but it is including the input value which is not the right output. For example, given the input value of 20, I need an output of 10.0 5.0 2.5 1.25 .0625 however, I am getting an output of 20, 10.0, 5.0, 2.5, 1.25 which is the incorrect answer. Any suggestions?

```
user_num = int(input())

while user_num >= 1.0:

    print(user_num, end='\n',)

    user_num = user_num / 2
```

Comment: Just switch the lines in the  while loop, do the division first then print the number

Answer (score 2):

Switch the order of the lines

```
print(user_num, end='\n',)    
user_num = user_num / 2
```

Answer (score -1):

```
user_num = int(input())

while(user_num >= 1):
    user_num = user_num/2
    print(user_num)
```

Comment: Hi @Kristina hand, welcome to stackoverflow.

While your code may well correct the issue of the original poster - some commentary around why your code works and the original does not would improve the quality of this answer.